# Join 2 table using Full outer join for MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I have 2 table to join using full outer join. I'm using Laravel 8 and using MS SQL Server as database. Below are my code:

In Controller:

```
$second = DB::table('src_squeeze_height')->rightJoin('src_casting', 'src_casting.2D_CODE', '=', 'src_squeeze_height.2D-CODE')
$castsqzh = DB::table('src_casting')->leftJoin('src_squeeze_height', 'src_casting.2D_CODE', '=', 'src_squeeze_height.2D-CODE')->unionAll($castsqzh)->get();
return view('table.finalscan', ['castsqzh' => $castsqzh]);
```

This code return error:

> syntax error, unexpected '$castsqzh' (T_VARIABLE)]

Where did I do wrong ?

Comment: You're using `unionAll($castsqzh)` before `$castsqzh` is defined. I think you want to do this `unionAll($second)`

Comment: Thank you for recommendation but the error still same

Comment: Every line in PHP must be closed by a semi-colon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Yup I accidentally miss the semi-colon, after I add that new error is occur which the :

Undefined variable: castsqzh

I clearly declare the variable for castsqzh

Comment: Need more context. I see `return` is this a function, and if so is the usage outside?

Comment: yup I want to display the result of join table to view